# Check validate status of textbox in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am using default validator that is provided by `.NET framework` which is `'TextMode=EMail'` and `'ValidateRequetMode=Enabled'` and I want to get them fired when button onclick is validated or not.

My purpose is to create like below function;

```
function func()
 {
  if(tbEmail.validated==true)
   {
     swal("PROCESSING...");
   }
 }
```

My aspx code is like below;

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbMail" minlength="1" runat="server" TextMode="Email" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbPassword" minlength="4" runat="server" TextMode="Password" MaxLength="12" required="" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server"  CssClass="ButtonClass" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" OnClientClick="return func();" />
```

How can I get that?

Comment: provide your aspx page code.

Comment: @GaurangDave edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbEmail" runat="server" TextMode="Email" />

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server"     
    ControlToValidate="tbEmail"
    ValidationExpression="^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$"
    ErrorMessage="Please provide a valid email address." 
    Display="Dynamic"/>
```

**NOTE:** This is just an example. You need to make changes as per need.

**OPTION-1**

You can add `ValidationGroup` to the validator. Then you can use `Page_ClientValidate(validationgroup)` method which returns a bool value. This method returns the status of validation result.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="revEmail" runat="server"     
    ControlToValidate="tbEmail"
    ValidationExpression="^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$"
    ErrorMessage="Please provide a valid email address." 
    Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="email"/>
```

Then you can write your function (as you asked for in question) to do further operation on different event.

```
<script>
function func()
{
  if(Page_ClientValidate("email"))
  {
    // Perform your operation
  }
}
</script>
```

**OPTION-2**

This is not the straight forward way to do it but technically possible.

Another thing, you can check visibility of validation message (validator generates an error message in case validation fails).

```
if (document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_revEmail").style.visibility == "hidden") {
  // text box validated successfully
} else {
  // error occured
}
```

Comment: this is not what i want. this is a shortcut. i want to get validatiıon status.

Comment: please wait a while for update. I am giving you update.

Comment: check updates in answer and now there are no further way. I suggest you to go with the option 1

Comment: how will you validate without validator?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found.

```
if (tbEmail.validity.valid == true) 
{
  // yays, it worked.
}
```